# Water Leaking From Upstairs Restroom Down to Basement Restroom

Tags: water, damage

I live in a two story split entry home. It has an upstairs and a basement. My restroom upstairs is right above the basement restroom. There is water leaking from the upstairs restroom down to the basement restroom. When we took a bath upstairs the water did not leak down to the basement restroom. It leaked through downstairs to the basement restroom when we took a shower. We are confused about what the issue could be. When we turned the shower on the water was dripping a lot onto the sink which cause the crack of the wall, above the light fixture and the ceiling to get wet. Any ideas on what could be causing this? I want to get it fixed as soon as possible before more damage can happen. Any ideas on the cost as well? In the picture you can kind of see where water damage happened. The wall became so sensitive we poked a hole through but just stuck a paper towel in to close it off for now. All answers are appreciated. Thank you!! [image]

Comment: We need a pictures of the tub/shower upstairs.  Especially of the area where tile meets tub. I suspect the joint where the tile meets the tub needs to be re-cauked.  Try running the shower with no one in it and the water aimed so it doesn't hit the walls, does it leak then?   Since you have low rep simply upload those to imgur.com and post links here. (Picture posting is limited when you are new.)

Comment: @Tyson wants you to determine if it's a failure in the shower body (piping that rises from the tub faucet to shower head) or a failure of caulking (from when water from the shower head hits some point that doesn't get wet while taking a bath).

Comment: Cost will depend greatly on whether it's just a failure in the shower surround/tile that can likely be easily fixed or a leak in the shower piping, which would require access to it. My guess is on the latter based on how you worded your question - "When we turned the shower on the water was dripping a lot onto the [downstairs] sink"

Comment: Thank you all so much for your responses. So we ran the water without it hitting the walls of the tub and it still leaks. Everything in the restroom is brand new as we just purchased our home less than a week ago. When I say brand new it is just the tile, flooring tile, sink, toilet. The house itself was built in 1978. Here are the pictures.

Comment: http://imgur.com/Wdcwuy0
http://imgur.com/ZEpuVsv

Comment: The previous owner did not disclose this defect or maybe the contractors that redid the surround tile somehow damaged the piping. It looks from your original picture that there is damage further down the corner so it's possible it's been leaking a while but nobody noticed. I'd call the realtor, inspector, etc to see what if any recourse you have in your area. You'll need to remove the tile (or possibly drywall behind the shower) to fix it. Could be anywhere from the valve up to the head spigot. I found copper pipe rotted away at top of the valve when I ripped out my bath.